# Dynamically Select Cells For Use in a VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba, function, dynamic, range

I've written the function below that I would like to use dynamically in my excel sheet where the function would assess the value of the variable selected in the formula and based on that value, perform a simple calculation referencing values in cells in different columns but in the same row.

I know that the code below works, but how can I rewrite the ranges so that my function can be used dynamically for each row of the same column?

```
Function AddedValue(TabSize As Integer)

Select Case TabSize

    Case 2
        AddedValue = Range("K3") * (Range("N3") * (Range("H3") * 0.001))

    Case 4
        AddedValue = Range("K3") * (Range("O3") * (Range("H3") * 0.001))

    Case 6
        AddedValue = Range("K3") * (Range("P3") * (Range("H3") * 0.001))

    Case 8
        AddedValue = Range("K3") * (Range("Q3") * (Range("H3") * 0.001))

    Case 10
        AddedValue = Range("K3") * (Range("R3") * (Range("H3") * 0.001))

End Select
End Function
```

Comment: The function will be used for example: =AddedValue(K3) in say, cell L3  so that when the user enters an interger (an even number) into the K3 cell, a dollar amount will appear in cell L3 which would correspond to which even number 2-10 that the user enters. I would like to use this function for each cell in a column this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an input for the row and then concatenate the row to your range strings.  Like so:

```
Function AddedValue(TabSize As Integer, iRow as Long)

Select Case TabSize

    Case 2
        AddedValue = Range("K" & iRow) * (Range("N" & iRow) * (Range("H" & iRow) * 0.001))

    Case 4
        AddedValue = Range("K" & iRow) * (Range("O" & iRow) * (Range("H" & iRow) * 0.001))

    Case 6
        AddedValue = Range("K" & iRow) * (Range("P" & iRow) * (Range("H" & iRow) * 0.001))

    Case 8
        AddedValue = Range("K" & iRow) * (Range("Q" & iRow) * (Range("H" & iRow) * 0.001))

    Case 10
        AddedValue = Range("K" & iRow) * (Range("R" & iRow) * (Range("H" & iRow) * 0.001))

End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `Cells` to access these ranges instead of `Range`.  `Cells` allows you to select the row and column as two separate arguments.  It's an extremely useful thing to learn if you're going to be doing more VBA in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Application.Caller to detect the cell that is running the Function:

```
Public Function AddedValue(TabSize As Integer)
    Application.Volatile
    r = Application.Caller.Row
    With Application.Caller.Parent.Rows(r)
        firstcell = .Cells(1, 11) ' column K
        Select Case TabSize
            Case 2
                secondcell = .Cells(1, 14) ' column N
            Case 4
                secondcell = .Cells(1, 15) ' column O
            Case 6
                secondcell = .Cells(1, 16) ' column P
            Case 8
                secondcell = .Cells(1, 17) ' column Q
            Case 10
                secondcell = .Cells(1, 18) ' column R
            End Select
        thirdcell = .Cells(8) ' column H
        AddedValue = firstcell * (secondcell * (thirdcell * 0.001))
    End With
End Function
```

Alternatively, if TabSize is uniform in the way your question suggests - you could also 'calculate' which column from it:

```
Public Function AddedValue2(TabSize As Integer)
    Application.Volatile
    r = Application.Caller.Row
    With Application.Caller.Parent.Rows(r)
        firstcell = .Cells(1, 11) ' column K
        secondcell = .Cells(1, 13 + (TabSize / 2)) ' dynamic column from TabSize
        thirdcell = .Cells(8) ' column H
        AddedValue2 = firstcell * (secondcell * (thirdcell * 0.001))
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Could you explain the use of the parentheses in the 'AddedValue2' line. I mean, is this some kind of trick to avoid an overflow?

Comment: Nope, nothing that clever I'm afraid @VBasic2008 . They're just still in there as they're in the example code the OP provided and I find leaving as much original structure in an answer as I can helps the OP compare it to their code.

Comment: Okay, I think I am beginning to understand the second solution especially. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the quick and easy way would be to pass the row as an argument to the function.

```
Function AddedValue(TabSize As Integer, row As Long)

Select Case TabSize
    Case 2
        AddedValue = Range("K" & row) * (Range("N" & row) * (Range("H" & row) * 0.001))
    Case 4
        AddedValue = Range("K" & row) * (Range("O" & row) * (Range("H" & row) * 0.001))
    Case 6
        AddedValue = Range("K" & row) * (Range("P" & row) * (Range("H" & row) * 0.001))
    Case 8
        AddedValue = Range("K" & row) * (Range("Q" & row) * (Range("H" & row) * 0.001))
    Case 10
        AddedValue = Range("K" & row) * (Range("R" & row) * (Range("H" & row) * 0.001))
End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be VBA? This formula only solution should work for you:

```
=$H3*0.001*$K3*INDEX($N3:$R3,,1)
```

The last `1` is the index of the column in that range (`N:R`) that you want.  So `1` = "Use column N" and `2` = "Use Column O" etc.  You can simply copy the formula and paste down rows and it will auto-adjust the row numbers while keeping the columns the same.

Additionally, if preferred, you can use a cell reference instead of hard-coding the "Selected Column/TabSize" number, like so (where the "Selected Column/TabSize" number in cell A1 in this example):

```
=$H3*0.001*$K3*INDEX($N3:$R3,,A1)
```

Comment: This is very useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Dynamic Cell Calculation

```
Option Explicit

Function AddedValue(TabSize As Long, row As Long) As Double

    Const cValue As String = "2,4,6,8,10"
    Const cStr1 As String = "K"
    Const cStr2 As String = "N,O,P,Q,R"
    Const cStr3 As String = "H"
    Const cDbl1 As Double = 0.001

    Dim vntV As Variant
    Dim vnt2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    vntV = Split(cValue, ",")
    vnt2 = Split(cStr2, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(vntV)
        If TabSize = CLng(Trim(vntV(i))) Then
            AddedValue = Range(cStr1 & row) * Range(Trim(vnt2(i)) & row) _
                    * Range(cStr3 & row) * cDbl1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```